# Finding marginal densities of $f (x,y) = c \sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2}, x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$

Tags: self-study, marginal-distribution, multivariable

As the title says, I'm looking for the marginal densities of $$f (x,y) = c \sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2}, x^2 + y^2 \leq 1.$$

So far I have found $c$ to be $\frac{3}{2 \pi}$. I figured that out through converting $f(x,y)$ into polar coordinates and integrating over $drd\theta$, which is why I'm stuck on the marginal densities portion. I know that $f_x(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)dy$, but I'm not sure how to solve that without getting a big messy integral, and I know the answer isn't supposed to be a big messy integral. Is it possible to instead find $F(x,y)$, and then take $\frac{dF}{dx}$ to find $f_x(x)$? That seems like the intuitive way to do it but I can't seem to find anything in my textbook that states those relationships, so I didn't want to make the wrong assumptions.

Comment: @kwak I'm not sure why changing the title was necessary...the "homework" tag should be sufficient.

Comment: @Shane:> ok changed back to the original.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Geometry helps here.  The graph of $f$ is a spherical dome of unit radius.  (It follows immediately that its volume is half that of a unit sphere, $(4 \pi /3)/2$, whence $c=3/(2 \pi)$.)  The marginal densities are given by areas of vertical cross-sections through this sphere.  Obviously each cross-section is a semicircle: to obtain the marginal density, find its radius as a function of the remaining variable and use the formula for the area of a circle.  Normalizing the resulting univariate function to have unit area turns it into a density.

Comment: Ahh, it's sort of coming back to me from multivariable calculus. I remember doing problems like that. How do I find the radius as a function of the remaining variable? It still seems like I'm going to have some sort of monster integral left over.

Comment: Let the remaining variable be $y$.  Then $x^2 \le 1-y^2$ describes the region over which you have to integrate.  Evidently the radius equals $\sqrt{1 - y^2}$, whence the cross-sectional area equals $\pi (1 - y^2)/2.$  That's a pretty simple formula :-).  (Remember, the theme here is geometry, not calculus...)

Comment: Oh, right. That crossed my mind, but it seemed too simple. I guess I was determined for it to be complicated. Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to ask: how does c figure into this?

Comment: In my opinion, Whuber's answer deserves to be upvoted for two reasons. First it answers the question asked, second as a model for how we could in the future handle (explicitly stated) homework questions: this type of answers actually contributes to the learning process and could be a better policy with respect to homework question than that adopted at MO/SO.

Comment: @Jarrod: you can use c to determine the normalization constant for the marginal density.  Alternatively, forget c, derive the functional form of the marginal (that is, up to a constant factor), then integrate the marginal to find its normalizing constant.

Comment: @Kwak: Thanks for pointing out there is a policy concerning homework questions!  I continued this discussion on meta at http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/12/919 .

Comment: In case anyone was dying to know if there was a way to solve this with calculus, you can instead recognize that $x = \sqrt{1-y^2}$ is of the form $u = \sqrt{a-b^2}$, which has the special integral $\int udx = \frac{1}{2}(xu + a^2 arcsin \frac{x}{a})$, which gives you the same result as wheber's method when integrated from $-\sqrt{1-y^2}$ to $\sqrt{1-y^2}$. My professor discussed this in class today, but I prefer wheber's method for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Jarrod: Thank you for the follow-up.  If the purpose of your course is to learn applications of calculus, then your professor's solution has pedagogical merit.  If it's to learn about probability, then seeing multiple solutions--including some relatively simple ones--can help you identify the key *probability* ideas and learn them better.  (The calculus stuff might then just be a distraction...)